# MacBook Pro crashes frequently

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, crash

I am currently facing severe issues with my MacBook Pro (Mid 2010) and my intuition tells me that it is probably a hardware problem only hard to fix. After all, I have used my machine for roughly six and a half years now. However, I want to make sure that I've tried anything not too complicated before going for a new one.

The chronology of the issues reads as follows: First, my WiFi broke down. There was just the "No hardware installed" message, when clicking the icon in the menu bar. A few days after, the screen started flickering (turning black for up to a second or two) and my external monitor seemed to loose signal from time to time as well. Again a few days later my MacBook started crashing. That could be twice within 5 or less minutes but sometimes it seems to run fine for a few hours even. This is the point where I am at right now. Sometimes, after a crash, when rebooting, the machine doesn't boot normally but instead shows me a screen where I could change my password.

What I've tried so far is switching users (which obviously had no effect) and resetting the SMC and PRAM. From what I can tell, my USB ports work fine. If this really is a hardware problem, which at this point seems to be the case with overwhelming probability, those measures are doomed to fail anyways.

My configuration is the following:

- MacBoook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010)
- 2.66 Ghz Intel Core i7
- 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB and Intel HD Graphics 288 MB
- 512 GB SSD

I run macOS Sierra (10.12). RAM and SSD are non-stock and I upgraded a while ago, say half a year back or even a bit longer.

An odd thing I stumbled across is that my CPU gets quite hot even under negligible load. For example, it was up to 80°C when just surfing the web yesterday (Safari with a few tabs open). The regular temperature under no load seems to be around 60-65°C, however, it can easily reach up to 90°C or even 100°C for no apparent reason. To me, this seems to be too much, even given the hardware's age.

In order to provide full detail, you can find a full crash report attached with the following link: http://pastebin.com/kStRYVuw

I don't always get these reports upon a crash, but I was able to snatch one yesterday. Unfortunately, I have no idea what causes the Read Error that seems to be the problem.

If any of you guys has an idea as to what I still could try before getting rid of my MacBook, I would appreciate it a great deal if you would share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a GPU panic meaning there could be trouble with your graphics chip.  Have you tried running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)?  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: On the off-chance that you can't get AHT to start as per Allan's suggestion, you can also try running it from the internet by holding both the Option and D keys down while booting up. Another thing to try is booting into Safe Mode. You can do this by holding the Shift key down during startup.

Comment: Can't even get into AHT. Neither directly nor via the internet.